# How can I download videos from this website?

Tags: firefox, video

I wanted to downlaod some of these short videos from chinadaily.com. For example,
http://video.chinadaily.com.cn/2013/1012/1388.shtml

I have tried NetVideoHunter with Firefox, which works for me for many other sites.  But here, NetVideoHunter shows me very small segments of less than 200 KB and when I try to play them (in the NVH panel itself), it says 'Connecting' and then 'Stream not found'.

I have seen other question on SuperUser about how to download a Flash video.   The URL shows something likes this for each segment.

```
http://videostream.chinadaily.com.cn:1935/app_1/_definst_/mp4:ugc/2013/1012/1762_video_9829_6_1381544755203.mp4/media_b580746_w1896927931.abst/Seg1-Frag80
```

Is there a way to download these videos?  Or is this method of segmenting done to prevent downloads?

Comment: You could try [VideoCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/video_cache_view.html).

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  I tried to install it, but I found that it is asking me to agree to install the Conduit engine, which I don't wish to do.  So I had to cancel the installation.

Comment: @Sathya,  sorry, I should have formatted the URL properly in my posting.  Thanks for doing it. I will try to remember in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most internet videos like this one aren't loaded in plaintext HTML that a video downloader would be able to locate and download. Sometimes they work, sometimes they don't, it all depends on how the website's video player is serving the content.

Going to the link in your post leads to me believe that the video player itself is needed to authenticate and stream the data.

One workaround is to use a screen recording software that can record section of the screen and record audio being played over the speakers. [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) is a pretty popular free solution. [BSR Screen Recorder](http://www.bsrsoft.com/downloadbsr.asp)  is a pretty good paid solution. I've used it before and it's worked well for me.

Comment: thanks for the information and suggestion.  I can't afford the BSR Screen Recorder, so I have not tried it.

Comment: I forgot BSR was not free. I updated my answer for one that is free, though I have not used it so I can't vouch for how well it will work for you.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I did not think about CamStudio. So, is it right to say that they do this (split into so many segments) to make it difficult to d/l?  BTW, I am unable to 'vote up' since I don't have the necessary reputation.

Comment: @user82171 No, it's really that the video player itself is "authenticating" or with their server and downloading the video, then playing it. Without authentication, the video won't play or download. There's really no way to tell for sure because most of this is taking place behind the scenes.